# PHP Mailer returns true but email is not received

Tags: php, phpmailer

I'm using PHP Mailer in my website for my contact form.

```
<?php 
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

    require 'phpmailer/PHPMailer/src/Exception.php'; 
    require 'phpmailer/PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
    require 'phpmailer/PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php';
    

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $message = $_POST['textarea'];
    $from = $_POST['email'];
    $to = "support@domain.com"; 
    $subject = 'email from website';



    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->Host   = "smtp.hostinger.com";
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
    $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;
    $mail->Port       = 465;
    $mail->Username   = $to;
    $mail->Password   = "mypassword";
    $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";
    $mail->From = $from;
    $mail->FromName = $name;
    $mail->addReplyTo($from, $name);
    $mail->Subject  = $subject;
    $mail->isHTML(true);
    $mail->Body = "Sender": " . $name . " " . $lastname . " \n <br/> Phone: ". $phone ." \r\n <br/> message: " . $message";;
    $mail->addAddress($to);


    
if(!$mail->Send())
{
   echo "Error sending: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
else
{
   echo 'success';
}

?>
```

Once I submit the contact form in my website the code above returns `success` message.

No email is actually received. I have double checked all the `$_POST`, the values are correct. Also double checked my username and password (I changed them in the question).

What can cause PHP Mailer to return success message and not send the email?

PHP Mailer debug

```
Sending with mail()<br>
Sendmail path: /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i<br>
Envelope sender: <br>
To: support@domain.com<br>
Subject: =?UTF-8?B?15nXpteZ16jXqiDXp9ep16gg157XlNeQ16rXqA==?=<br>
Headers: Date: Sun, 19 Sep 2021 09:37:31 +0000From: test11 &lt;test@gmail.com&gt;Reply-To: test11 &lt;test@gmail.com&gt;Message-ID: &lt;sK7qvbbNwmP2IikzBwV7c2mD3TqDUGwEOLeW2HZng@www.reboost.co.il&gt;X-Mailer: PHPMailer 6.5.1 (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)MIME-Version: 1.0Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8<br>
Result: true<br>
```

Comment: You're not checking the return value of `$mail->send()`. It returns `false` if sending the mail failed.

Comment: `What can cause PHP Mailer to return success message`...you don't know whether it's returning the success message because you're not checking. You just always echo "success" regardless. Check the return value of the send() function. It can fail without there being a PHP exception.

Comment: @rickdenhaan the try and catch is checking if `$mail->send()` return true or false.
Either way, I used `if(!$mail->send())` and same result accord.

Comment: `the try and catch is checking if $mail->send() return true or false`...no it doesn't. Try/catch checks whether an exception occurs. That has nothing to do with the return value of the function.

Comment: You need to tell phpMailer to use smtp `$mail->isSMTP();`

Comment: @rickdenhaan Updated my question, still same result

Comment: Note that its also possible for an email to be _sent_ successfully but still never be _received_. Lots of things can go wrong in between (usually spam filters but there are other possibilities too). Make sure you're distinguishing between that and a total failure to send.

Comment: If `$mail->send()` returns `true`, then your server was successfully instructed to send the message (either using `sendmail` or the remote SMTP server). From that point on, it's out of PHP's hands. If the message is not received, did it end up in your spam folder? Is a rejection/bounce message sent to the `$from` address? If not, there may be more information in your mail server's logs.

Comment: @Mattigins that acctually returned me an error `Error sending: SMTP Error: The following recipients failed:  support@domain.com: <test@gmail.com>: Sender address rejected: not owned by user support@domain.com`

Comment: The clue is in the debug message. It's not being sent with smtp `Sending with mail()`

Comment: @YotamDahan I believe this is an error in authenticating for smtp. Check your user/password

Comment: Sometimes the "from" needs to be the same as your login username address for anti-spam purposes

Comment: @Mattigins That is correct! thank you, please write your answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to tell phpMailer to use SMTP

`$mail->isSMTP();`

OP replied stating the following error:

```
Error sending: SMTP Error: The following recipients failed:  support@domain.com: <test@gmail.com>: Sender address rejected: not owned by user support@domain.com
```

This can be caused by having the "from" field differ from the smtp login name.